# Using AIDL file in other application module

Tags: android, ipc, android-source, aidl, android.mk

I have one aidl interface and this one is implemented by A app and B app wants to use that aidl. 
In A app Android.mk

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += src/com/a/simple/ISimpleInterface.aidl

LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES += src/com/a/simple/ISimpleInterface.aidl
```

In B App i have just imported aidl interface as below

```
import com.a.ISimpleInterface;
```

But while module building for B app gives Error like "the com.a cannot be resolved".

Answer (score 0):

`LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES` is a directory, not a file. Also, it does not inherit the $(LOCAL_PATH). So, you probably need to set

```
LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES += $(A_APP_PATH)/src
```

Comment: Added what you suggested but still other application is not able to use the aidl..

Comment: The 'other' application must see the aidl files, not the origin. I have fixed the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you have any documentation link for variable `LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES`?  From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27408433/3066295), I found it may be from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/base_rules.mk

Comment: Since [August 2015](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/956dcccf76bb176b45cc098808cb7ac5dcb5e8f7), this code has been moved from **base_rules.mk** to **java.mk**. The current [**master**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/ff14c47182a7636477432dee294dd14e9f4b1935/core/java.mk) still uses `LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES`. This source shows how `LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES` is used by Google to build the Android platform. It is often a reasonable clue to the way they expect you to use it in your project, but it is by no means a bounding contract.